# Snowflake Set USER name to login_name for multiple users

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake. I wanted to replace the "name" column of USERS with the "login_name" for multiple users.

I can do this for one user like this:

```
ALTER USER "NAME_SURNAME_COMPANY" RENAME TO "NAME@EMAIL.COM";
```

I can get all the users that I want to target using:

```
show USERS;
select * from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where "login_name" like '%@EMAIL.COM';
```

**Note that the "name" column of USERS has the format NAME_SURNAME_COMPANY and I want to change this to the "login_name" in the format NAME.SURNAME@EMAIL.COM**

How can I do this recursively over multiple users?

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SET_NAME_TO_LOGIN_NAME()
  returns varchar
  language sql
  as
  $$
  declare
      show USERS;
      c1 CURSOR for select * from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where "login_name" like '%@EMAIL.COM' AS NAMES;
      SQL STRING;
    begin
      for record in c1 do         
         SQL := 'ALTER USER ' || record.names || ' RENAME TO c1.login_name;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL;
       end for;
      return :SQL;
    end;
  $$;
CALL SET_NAME_TO_LOGIN_NAME();
```

I don't think I'm on the right path here though. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is one time operation, then first step is to generte all queries:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER USER ', u.name, ' RENAME TO ', u.login_name, ';') AS query
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS AS u
WHERE u.login_name LIKE '%@EMAIL.COM';

-- alternatively
SHOW USERS;
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER USER ', u."name", ' RENAME TO ', u."login_name", ';') AS query
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) AS u
WHERE u."login_name" LIKE '%@EMAIL.COM';
```

Second step is copying the output to new worksheet and running all queries.

Comment: Hi @Lukasz, thanks for your answer. I have a couple of questions though:
When I run the above query, it gives me this error:
```
SQL compilation error: Shared database is no longer available for use. It will need to be re-created if and when the publisher makes it available again.
```
Where is the USERS table generally located if it's not under SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE?

Comment: @csgarun [Users view](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/users.html) - the location of the system view is Snowflake database(share). If you do not have access to it then the approach of `SHOW USERS` and `RESULTSET_SCAN` is alo an option

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: I tried this:
```
show USERS;
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER USER ', u.NAME, ' RENAME TO ', u.LOGIN_NAME, ';') AS query
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) AS u where u.LOGIN_NAME like '%@EMAIL.COM';
```
Got this error: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 29 invalid identifier 'U.NAME'

Comment: @csgarun When you are using `SHOW USERS` then all identifiers have to be qouted, i.e, `u.NAME` => `u."name"` etc